# Retrieve object from database via hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I'm creating a hibernate app and I'm able to save data to dtb via `hibernate`. Nevertheless I wasn't able to figure out, how to retrieve data from database. Could anybody show me, how to do that in some way, that will be similar to the way, I save data? I've been googling a lot, but everything, I didn't find anything, that would look like my way... E.g. they used a lot of annotations etc. I'm quite new to hibernate, so it's possible, that this is not a good way, how to create hibernate applications. If so, pls write it in a comment.

Part of my `UserDAOImpl`:

```
UserDAO user;

public UserDAOImpl() {
    user = new UserDAO();
}

public void createUser(int id, String Username, String CreatedBy) {
    user.setUserId(id);
    user.setUsername(Username);
    user.setCreatedBy(CreatedBy);
    user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
}

public void saveUser() {
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   session.beginTransaction();      
   session.save(user);
   // save the data to the database
   session.getTransaction().commit();
   // close the connection
   session.disconnect();
}


public void findUser() {
     // ????????????
}
```

UserDAO:

```
public class UserDAO implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * generated serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6440259681541809279L;

    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdDate;

    public UserDAO() {
    }

    public UserDAO(int userId, String username, String createdBy,
            Date createdDate) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table name is User, here is the sample code to get a User data for an input userId:

```
public User findUserById(int userId) {
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   String queryString = "from User where userId = :userId";  
   Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);  
   query.setInteger("userId", userId);  
   Object queryResult = query.uniqueResult();  
   UserDAO user = (UserDAO)queryResult;
}
```

Comment: so even when I'm using `hibernate`, I must use SQL queries? I was thinking that it will go easier like when I was saving that object to dtb :-/ ...or I would not say easier...but without SQL

Comment: and in addition - why sould I write there name of the table? I've got it already in `User.hbm.xml` ...

Comment: You really don't have to. There are easier ways to simply retrieve everything without writing HQL. I believe this tutorial should help you learning that: http://blog.patouchas.net/technology/hibernate-dao-java-tutorial/

Comment: Splendid! That idea of usage abstract classes and interfaces is just genious! Thx for that link :) Btw-if anyone would read it - it's already a little bit deprecated, so some small improvements will be needed

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've found answer in another poste here, on SO.

```
// finds user by ID
public UserDAO findUserById(int userId) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO) session.get(UserDAO.class, userId);
    session.disconnect();
    return userDAO;
}
```